# I want to number my subsubsection and number it in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried to use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

to include the subsubsection with a number before it into my TOC.
But it doesn't work. Then I found something in my template. But the original setting is subsection, and I turned them into subsubsection. But it still does not work. Any one help?

```
% replace subsection with subsub
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
```

[image]

Comment: Which template do you use? Please provide a complete minimal working example.

Comment: Actually, it is a thesis template, very complex.

Comment: Actually, I have Chapter, Section, Subsection in the text. And they are standard template, but there is an item of subsubsection level in my own text.

Comment: Does your template base on `memoir`. This is the only document class providing `\maxsecnumdepth`.

Comment: yes, i found the first line is  \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template base on the documentclass `memoir`. So in your question you are showing the correct answer:

The following MWE results to:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco. But why it does not work after the text has been compiled.

Comment: Sorry, it works now. I turned off the editor and open it again. So it works. Thank you very much Marco.

Comment: I saw that button.